# node.js - need help choosing a templating engine valid both client & server side with express

Tags: node.js, template-engine

I want to code an application with Node.js where templates and rendering code out of json would be the same on client & server side.

I would have like to use jquery templates as there is a port of jquery templates to Node.js through https://github.com/kof/node-jqtpl.

Nevertheless, with this solution, the templates would be shared but not the rendering code.

Is there a templating solution where the template & rendering code would be the same ?

Thank you for your help

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/
Can be used on both server side and browser. Mustache is pretty awesome itself, never used it with Node.js per say, but had a go at it with Go, and it was nice.
Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

try [ICanHaz](https://github.com/andyet/ICanHaz.js).

It's really really beautiful and easy to use. you can find an introduction [here](http://icanhazjs.com/).